# Compare two columns with different set of conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yysXz.png)The following formula compares the values of two different columns using some existing conditions which i want to add to.

```
=IF(AND(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,A2,""))=5,FIND(A2,B2&A2)=1),"","Invalid")
```

**Existing conditions:**

**1.** If the value in column A is 2 digits then  subsequent cell must have 7 digits and it must start with the same 2 digits which column A is having

**2.** If the value in column A is 3 digits subsequent cell must have 8 digits and should start with same 3 digits which column A is having.

**3.** If one of the cell is blank it captures that too.

**I want to add 2 more features into the formula :-**

**1.** If the value is not numeric in any of the cell mention invalid

**2.** As of now if both the cells are blank it gives invalid but it should not be the case.

How can i achieve this with Excel formula?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z672M.png)

Comment: @Lakmi Thanks for editing

Comment: @QHarr thanks for making it clear enough.

Comment: Existing condition 3 is still not clear to me. Did you mean if either of the two columns is not empty?

Comment: if either of the two columns is empty is an error, the formula captures this. but i want to add if both the columns/cells are empty the formula must pass it as valid.

Comment: i think both exising number 3 and desired number 3 need editing to make it absolutely clear what you mean.

Comment: With VBA, doing some code. Do you have a code you are already working with?

Comment: @JonSmith, try `=IF(AND(LEN(A2)>0,LEN(B2)>0),IF(AND(ISNUMBER(A2),ISNUMBER(B2),LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,A2,""))=5,FIND(A2,B2&A2)=1),"","Invalid"),"")`. But this has nothing to do with `VBA`.

Comment: To be fair, OP said VBA or Excel formula so helpful to show it can be solved just with Excel formula.

Comment: @Arul Is there a typo in your formula? I think at least the first And needs another bracket. And is the OP saying, if both blank evaluate to TRUE? Suggest maybe a larger encompassing OR to handle both blank or the other conditions as stated.

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question but i thought the following example would be True, cell A2 = 11, cell B2 = 1111111. It evaluates to Invalid. So i guess i am asking, have i misunderstood the question, are there more rules, or is the formula incorrect as stated?

Comment: @QHarr, I guess when both the cells are blank, the evaluation needs to be skipped and not display any result. About the formula, I think, there is no typo, but some junk is added by formatting as code. Also, the case A2=11 and B2=1111111, issue is with `SUBSTITUE` which replaces all the 11 as the numbers are repeating. When you try with A2=12 and B2=1234567, it works.

Comment: @Arul I think your assumption is a good one for the skipping evaluation but the case i stated, of 11 and 1111111, makes me wonder if we are missing some rules as this fits the rules as described which is exactly why i chose it...Hmmmmm.

Comment: i appreciate all of your efforts but this formula is not working it throws an error reading "use function to insert the formula"

Comment: This formula would cover the case stated above. Please give it a try. `=IF(AND(LEN(A2)>0,LEN(B2)>0),IF(AND(ISNUMBER(A2),ISNUMBER(B2),LEN(B2)-LEN(A2)=5,LEFT(B2,LEN(A2))=LEFT(A2,LEN(A2))),"","Invalid"),"")`

Comment: @JonSmith, I am not getting any errors. Can you please give the latest formula a try?

Comment: @Arul i have attached a screenshot of error i am getting in the question itself. please go through that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `=IF(AND(LEN(A2)<>0,ISERROR(A2/B2)),"Invalid",IF(AND(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,A2,""))=5,FIND(A2,B2&A2)=1),"",IF(AND(B2=A2,LEN(A2)=0),"","Invalid")))`

Comment: This still fails the test of A2 = 11 and B2 = 1111111. Is there another rule?

Comment: I changed the formula to cover also this case     `=IFERROR(IF(AND(LEN(A2)<>0,OR(ISERROR(A2/B2),ISERROR(B2/A2))),"Invalid",IF(AND(A2=IFERROR(LEFT(B2,LEN(A2))*1,0),LEN(B2)-LEN(A2)=5),"",IF(AND(B2=A2,LEN(A2)=0),"","Invalid"))),"Invalid")`

Comment: Add + 1 for covering this additional case